# Implementing the command pattern using generics

Tags: c#, generics, interface, command-pattern

I'm trying to implement the command pattern, so it works like this:

- There is a base class `Command<T>`, from which all other commands inherit.
- A command can be executed on a class deriving from an `Actor`.
- Each interface defines an action an `Actor` can perform. E.g. `IMovable` or `ITurnable`.
- Each command class acts on a specific interface. E.g. `Command<IMovable>`.
- Actors implement interfaces, which define what actions they can perform.

Here is how I tried implementing it:

```
// base interface for all action interfaces
public interface ICommandable { }

// interface for a move action
public interface IMovable : ICommandable
{
    void Move();
}

// base actor class
public class Actor : ICommandable
{
    public void ExecuteCommand(ICommand<ICommandable> command)
    {
        (command as Command<ICommandable>).Execute(this);
    }
}

// an actor which can be moved
public class MovableActor: Actor, IMovable
{
    public void Move()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Move");
    }
}

// an interface for commands
public interface ICommand<out T> { }

// base command class
public class Command<T> : ICommand<T> where T : ICommandable
{
    public virtual void Execute(T robot) { }
}

// move command
public class MoveCommand : Command<IMovable>
{
    public override void Execute(IMovable actor)
    {
        actor.Move();
    }
}
```

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
MovableActor actor = new MovableActor();
Command<IMovable> cmd = new MoveCommand();
actor.ExecuteCommand(cmd);
```

The issue with my implementation is that the `ICommand` interface has to use the `out` keyword for its parameter. I did some reading and I understand why that is, but I don't know how to achieve what I described. How can I implement this?

If this is not possible, how should I change my description, so it's as close to this one as possible, but works?

Comment: I don't understand why you need `ICommand` at all. If I remove it, your code still compiles fine. It also compiles fine if I remove the `out`

Comment: @canton7 The code compiles fine, but when I try to create a `MoveCommand` and pass it to `ExecuteCommand()` of the `MovableActor`, it doesn't work.

Comment: If would be helpful if you included that code in your question

Comment: The basic problem here is that your `MoveCommand.Execute` *must* be given an `IMovable` -- that method depends on having an `IMovable`. However, you're allowed to pass anything to `Actor.ExecuteCommand`, even a command such as an `ICommand<ITurntable>`: there's nothing stopping you doing this. But if you did that, and called `MoveCommand.ExecuteCommand` with an `ICommand<ITurntable>`, `MoveCommand.Execute` would fail, because it wants an `IMovable`.

Comment: @canton7 I added an example. 
Now I see why it can't work like this. How could I modify this to be as similar as possible, but work?

Comment: Either you don't let actors invoke commands on themselves: invoke the command directly on the actor, or have a separate CommandInvoke take both the action and the command.... Or prepare for the possibility that someone might send a command to an actor which can't accept that, and check for that and deal with it at runtime. Then it's just `Actor.ExecuteCommand(ICommand command)`, and you do a runtime check to see whether it's the right sort of command

Comment: ... Something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uQ5CZH

Comment: @canton7 Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. If you want, add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem here is that your `MoveCommand.Execute` must be given an `IMovable` -- that method depends on having an `IMovable`. However, you're allowed to pass anything to `Actor.ExecuteCommand`, even a command such as an `ICommand<ITurntable>`: there's nothing stopping you doing this.

But if you did that, and called `MoveCommand.ExecuteCommand` with an `ICommand<ITurntable>`, `MoveCommand.Execute` would fail, because it wants an `IMovable`.

Your basic options are:

1. Either you don't let actors invoke commands on themselves: invoke the command directly on the actor, or have a separate `CommandInvoker` take both the action and the command
2. Prepare for the possibility that someone might send a command to an actor which can't accept that, and check for that and deal with it at runtime. Then it's just `Actor.ExecuteCommand(ICommand command)`, and you do a runtime check to see whether it's the right sort of command.

That would look something like:

```
// base interface for all action interfaces
public interface ICommandable { }

// interface for a move action
public interface IMovable : ICommandable
{
    void Move();
}

// base actor class
public abstract class Actor : ICommandable
{
    public void ExecuteCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        command.Execute(this);
    }
}

// an actor which can be moved
public class MovableActor: Actor, IMovable
{
    public void Move()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Move");
    }
}

// an interface for commands
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute(ICommandable robot);
}

// base command class
public abstract class Command<T> : ICommand where T : ICommandable
{
    void ICommand.Execute(ICommandable robot)
    {
        if (robot is T typedRobot)
        {
            Execute(typedRobot);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle this error
        }
    }
    
    protected abstract void Execute(T robot);
}

// move command
public class MoveCommand : Command<IMovable>
{
    protected override void Execute(IMovable actor)
    {
        actor.Move();
    }
}
```